# Python-how to plot non numerical time series

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I would like to plot time series records of activities. My data is as follows:

```
Day 1: Activity 1 (9am), Activity 2(10am) ...
Day 2: Activity 2 (9am), Activity 5(10:15am)...
```

I have an idea, of plotting 2 axis, the first axis is time in a day (24 hours), and the second axis is for different days. The different activities are represented using different colors.

Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ukc6.jpg

How can I do it in Python? Or there's a better way to do it?

Comment: ...and the duration of the activities is always 1 hour, or where is this information stored? And generally, how is your data structured - is it a `pandas` dataframe? Can you post a real sample of the data, not only a hint which kind of values you might have in some undescribed dataformat...?

Comment: If you want to do that with `matplotlib` I'd recommend to look at `broken_barh` https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/broken_barh.html

Comment: @SpghttCd A quick look. seems like what I need. Thanks